# Edit text inside div with absolute positioned image inside?

Tags: html, css

I have a div-element which should be used to add a keyword to it. Therefore, I am using the contenteditable attribute for the div on a double click. This works well. The problem is that there should be an absolute positioned image inside the div. So when I do a double click, the image is selected and removed if I input some text.

The html code is the following:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="tag"><img src="delete.svg" class="deleteIcon"></div>
```

How can I prevent the removement of the inner image element? E.g. making it unselectable or allow content editable only on text. I tried to set contenteditable to plaintext-only, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the image need to be absolutely positioned, it doesn't really matter which div it's inside. I used another wrapping `div`.

```css
.deleteIcon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.tag {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tag-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-wrapper">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/32" class="deleteIcon">

  <div contenteditable="true" class="tag">

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is also my approach right now and it works.